# Variables out of scope in main when called by reference by a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference, program-entry-point

I have made the following code, whose output should generate a point uniformly at random on the unit circle centered at the origin:

```
#include "unif.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void point_on_circle(double& x, double& y)
{
 double r;

do
    {
    double x = unif(-1.,1.);
    double y = unif(-1.,1.);
    double r = x*x + y*y;
    }
    while (r >=1.0);

    x = x / sqrt(r);
    y = y / sqrt(r);
}

int main()
{

 cout << "Pair of points on the circle found is " << x << " and " << y << endl;
 cout << "Let's verify: x^2+y^2=" << x*x+y*y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The header "unif.h" is just a file that contains a function void unif(double x, double y), that produces uniformly random numbers in the interval (x,y), and it works perfectly (already tested). 
The problem is that when I build the program then it gives me (of course) the error in the main:

"error: 'x' was not declared in this scope"

which is clear since of course x is defined outside the main and never defined in main(). I cannot figure out how to tell the compiler that the values of x and y found by the function point_on_circle should be "carried" inside the main. How could I fix this code? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The compiler is correct. Where do you think x is defined?

Comment: Don Scott, below, is absolutely correct.  You may want to study up on scope and how it affects your objects.

Answer (score 2):

**In your main method you did not declare a variable called `x` nor `y`.**  Moreover, you also have scoping issues in your `point_on_circle(double& x, double& y)` function with the variable `r`.

**[Please review C++ scoping.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined x in the do-while loop, so you cannot use it outside the loop, since those definitions hide the parameters x and y.  Define it before the loop:

```
void point_on_circle(double& x, double& y)
{
    double r;

    do
    {
        x = unif(-1.,1.);
        y = unif(-1.,1.);
        r = x*x + y*y;
    }while (r >=1.0);

    x = x / sqrt(r);
    y = y / sqrt(r);
}
```

Comment: Ironically, the compiler isn't even getting to this function.   Look at `main`...  The OP needs to review scoping.

Comment: Ah, right, I guess that's the source of his "error", although based on the original version of print_on_circle, The while loop is going to do nothing, as the calculated x,y values will not be used when dividing by sqrt()

Answer (score -1):

You have a few issues.
1) you need to declare x and y inside main.
2) you never, ever actually call point_on_circle. At all. 
3) finally, as others noted, you mask parameters x and y in your do loop.

With all of that said, it looks like you're attempting to find a random point on the unit circle. with that in mind, I would remove the do loop entirely and just do this:

```
void point_on_circle(double& x, double& y)
{
    double r;
    x = unif(-1.,1.);
    y = unif(-1.,1.);
    r = x*x + y*y;
    x = x / sqrt(r);
    y = y / sqrt(r);
}
```

It gives the exact same result while avoiding a (potential) endless loop, and certainly avoids useless extra processing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes I understand that the errors are those you recalle, however, my question was exactly: how can I declare x and y inside the main? x and y have been determined by the function, suppose x=a and y=b. Now, if I just declare "double x" "double y" in the main, I simply lose the values a and b stored in x and y, right? My problem is that I would like to keep them.

Comment: Ah, but with your main, x and y haven't been determined by anything.'

`int main()  
{  
  double x,y;  
  point_on_circle(x,y);  
  cout << "Pair of points on the circle found is " << x << " and " << y << endl;  
 cout << "Let's verify: x^2+y^2=" << x*x+y*y << endl;  
 return 0;  
}  
`

Comment: Yes, now it works perfectly, thank you! It was exactly what I wanted to ask, how to call in the main variables x and y that have been determined by a function without losing the values already determined for those variables in the function. You got what I wanted to ask, I just needed to add the declaration of the variable *plus* the declaration of the function itself, which is I was missing. You figured that out. Thank you again.

Comment: The code by WingedPanther73 above does not pick a point uniformly in the unit circle.  There will be more points selected by the above algorithm near the diagonals than there will be points selected near the axis, as the area of the points in the source-square mapping near the diagonals is larger than the area of the points in the source-square mapping near the axis.

Comment: just edit out the bad math, and this is a good answer for the programming issues.  For the math, how about r=1.0, angle=unif(0, 2*pi) and use sin and cos to convert that to x,y?

Comment: I based the math on what was in the original question. My guess is he's a student learning how to call functions. Changing the implementation of unif could "solve" the problem of even distribution.

Comment: @Yak wrong. The algorithm works perfectly to find uniformly generated points in the unit circle. Also, I don't understand what is "the area of the points" that you mention.

Comment: @RandomGuy The algorithm first picks a point uniformly from the unit square.  Then it projects that point onto the unit circle.  The points in a wedge of the square, of angle theta, with the wedge's "sharp corner" at the origin, are projected onto an arc of the unit circle of angle theta by the projection.  The area of this wedge (as a fraction of the original square) give you the probability that the point is on that particular arc.  The area of the wedge is larger when pointed at the corners than when pointed at the middle of the face of the square.  Do I need to mspaint it?

Comment: @RandomGuy Note that the above algorithm (by Panther) is different than your algorithm.  Yours does not have that particular flaw, due to your `while` loop.  Panther fails to discard points outside the unit circle, and hence screws up the probabilities.

Comment: @WingedPanther73 Nobody who posted in the comments before you will notice your comments unless you target them at someone.  Use @ user name to "ping" that username with a notification that you are responding to them.